# Processed SASS file missing vendor prefix from custom mixin

Tags: css, sass, mixins, scss-mixins

I am trying to convert from CSS to SASS and having trouble making a vendor prefix mixin for the transform property only. Any help or pointers is appreciated as I can't see where I am going wrong and I have tried Googling around with no luck.

**Issue** - Once SASS has processed it is stripping out the vendor prefix where it only includes the transform property.

Bellow is the sample output I am trying to achieve -

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px); 
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
        transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
```

Mixin -

```
@mixin transform-prefix($values...) {
  @each $vendor in ('-webkit-', '-ms-', '') {
    #{$vendor}transform: #{$values};
  }
}
    
&.active .line1 {
  @include transform-prefix(rotate(-45deg), translate(-9px, 6px));
}
```

Output -

```
.slide-nav-button.active .line1 {
  transform: rotate(-45deg), translate(-9px, 6px);
}
```

I have also tried this mixin but it strips out the prefix -

```
@mixin transform-prefix($values...) {
  -webkit-transform: $values;
      -ms-transform: $values;
          transform: $values;
  }
```

Comment: Just tried this but without the comma: `transform-prefix(rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px));` and it outputs with the prefixes

Comment: @Daniel_Knights - I still get the same output after changing to your suggestion. I am currently using Live SASS compiler extension in VS Code if this info helps in anyway.

Comment: I am going to answer my own post here but it's to do with Live SASS Compiler settings.

https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-sass-compiler/blob/master/docs/settings.md

Answer can be found in here.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to respond.
but I'm going to fix this by only moving transform: into the first line of mixin
look like this

```html
@mixin myBox($rot) {
  transform: $rot;
  -webkit-transform: $rot;
  -ms-transform: $rot;
   }
```